# How to get recipient email address from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to get the `.To` email address from my sent box using Excel-VBA. However, `To` only returns  the name not the email address. After some search  found that the `recipient` should be what I'm looking for. Tried by following the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient) guide, but the code does not seem to work.

```
Sub test()

Dim objoutlook As Object 
Dim objNamespace As Object 
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim OutlookMail As outlook.MailItem

Set objoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set objNamespace = objoutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
Set olFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail) 
Set OutlookMail = objoutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim recips As outlook.Recipients
    Dim recip As outlook.Recipient
    Dim pa As outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
    Set recips = OutlookMail.Recipients
    For Each recip In recips    'Something is wrong here
        Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
        Debug.Print recip.Name & " SMTP=" & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
    Next


Set olFolder = Nothing 
Set objNamespace = Nothing 
Set objoutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm not really familiar with VBA, please guide along.

Comment: You create an item, with no recipients, rather than using the items in the Sent Items folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Private Sub GetRecipientSMTP(objAllRecip As Outlook.Recipients)

    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim objExDisUser As Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList

    For Each objRecip In objAllRecip
        Select Case objRecip.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType
        Case 0, 10
            Set objExUser = objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
            If Not objExUser Is Nothing Then _
            Debug.Print objExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress '/* or copy somewhere */

        Case 1
            Set objExDisUser = objRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList
            If Not objExDisUser Is Nothing Then _
            Debug.Print objExDisUser.PrimarySmtpAddress '/* or copy somewhere */
        Case Else
        '/* Do nothing, recipient not recognized */
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
```

You can run it in your sub like below using `recips` from your code (or see sample usage).

```
GetRecipientSMTP recips
```

Basically, this will check on the each `Recipient` on `Recipients` you supplied.
 Then will check if it is an `ExchangeUser` type or `ExchangeDistributionList` before returning the `PrimartSMTPAddress`. HTH.

**Sample Usage:**

```
Sub marine()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim i As Integer

    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '/* assuming OL is running */
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    With olFolder
        For i = .Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            If TypeOf .Items(i) Is MailItem Then
                Set olMail = .Items(i)
                GetRecipientSMTP olMail.Recipients
            End If
            Exit For '/* I just want to process the first mail */
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

<sub>**Note:** I used early binding and set reference to Outlook Object Library.</sub>

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, Can you also show an example where the `sub` can be ran straightaway? Had trouble understanding the msdn example.

Comment: @ppz Added it. But make sure that you have a valid `outlook mail recipients object`.

Comment: @ppz Actually, the one from MSDN link is working too. You just have to strip the email address from the output which is after the `=` sign. This is what I get when I use that procedure. `Doe, John SMTP=John.Doe@mycompany.com`. The first part is the name followed by the SMTP. Suggested procedure above outputs the email address or the `PrimarySMTP`.

Comment: Thanks, will test it out. Properly because I didn’t do my recipient object correctly.

Answer (score 0):

*Quick Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim OUTLOOK_APP As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim SENT_FLDR As MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim olRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim olRecipAddress As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set OUTLOOK_APP = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = OUTLOOK_APP.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set SENT_FLDR = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set Items = SENT_FLDR.Items

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If Items(i).Class = olMail Then

            For Each olRecip In Items(i).Recipients
                olRecipAddress = olRecip.Address
                Debug.Print olRecipAddress
            Next

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, the output doesn't seem right. Example : `OU=EXTernal (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)/cn=Recipients/cn=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` & `ou=Exchange Administrative Group (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)/cn=Recipients/cn=xxxxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

this is my way of getting Recipient email Address. I hope it would help you.

```
Sub CopyCurrentContact()

   Dim objRcp As Outlook.Recipient
   Dim objRcpS As Outlook.Recipients
   Dim rcpStr As String
   Set outLookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set InspectorObj = outLookObj.ActiveInspector
   Set ItemObj = InspectorObj.CurrentItem



  Set objRcpS = ItemObj.Recipients

  For Each objRcp In objRcpS

    rcpStr = objRcp.Address & "; " & rcpStr

    Debug.Print rcpStr
  Next objRcp





End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!